# Pre-trim PNG image to alpha and get offsets

Tags: image, image-processing, imagemagick

I have a set of images, all with the same size, saved in PNG format.

Later, in my program, I'll use these images and superimpose them on top of each other.

However the non-transparent part of each of these images are actually very small. So in order to improve performance, it would be better to use images trimmed to alpha, so that each image is cropped to the smallest possible rectangle containing all non-alpha pixels.

When drawing each image on top of the other, I would then only need to draw that cropped image with an offset.

The there are *a lot* of images, so it shouldn't be done manually - nor is it something I would like to do at first start of my program.

In other words, I'm looking to create some batch job that can handle this efficiently.

ImageMagick has "trim" which does what I'm looking for, except that I need to capture the offset. This offset then needs to accompany the image in some way - either by writing the offsets to a file, or putting it in the file name (e.g. overlay123.png could become overlay123-34x99.png if the offset is 34x99).

What is the best tool for the job? I could write such a routine to do it manually, but it seems like there should be a few command-line utilities I could use, or do it in a few rows in some scripting language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting from the simple trim command:

```
convert test.png -trim +repage test2.png
```

you can add `-identify` operator:

```
convert test.png -trim -identify +repage test2.png
```

the output of this command will be:

```
test.png PNG 800x600=>566x483 800x600+161+52 8-bit DirectClass 0.000u 0:00.004
```

where 800x600 is the size of the original image, 566x483 is the size of the resulting image and +161+52 is the offset of the rectangle containing the non alpha part of the picture. Using the latter information you should be able to build a little script to achieve your goal.